# Draw a shape with ،TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

[image]

I've drawn this picture, but not like this

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
%\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}
%  \definecolor{myaqua}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{HTML}{21bdbe}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{HTML}{19bfe0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(3.2557266494472623,-1.6520962393119207) rectangle (12.29163742054479,5.813639873201507);
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (3.6,-1.2) -- (11.6,-1.2) -- (8.,5.8) -- cycle;
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (7.2,3.6) -- (7.2,4.4) -- (11.6,4.4) -- (11.6,3.6) -- cycle;
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (7.,3.) -- (7.,2.2) -- (11.6,2.2) -- (11.584597952190476,2.9736025163350672) -- cycle;
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (11.6,1.6) -- (11.6,0.8) -- (6.8,0.8) -- (6.8,1.6) -- cycle;
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (11.6,0.2) -- (11.6,-0.6) -- (6.6,-0.6) -- (6.6,0.2) -- cycle;
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (7.972370141039504,5.756043406199211) -- (7.832933908904861,-1.2) -- (11.6,-1.2) -- cycle;
\draw [color=zzttqq] (3.6,-1.2)-- (11.6,-1.2);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (11.6,-1.2)-- (8.,5.8);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (8.,5.8)-- (3.6,-1.2);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (7.2,3.6)-- (7.2,4.4);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (7.2,4.4)-- (11.6,4.4);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.6,4.4)-- (11.6,3.6);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.6,3.6)-- (7.2,3.6);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (7.,3.)-- (7.,2.2);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (7.,2.2)-- (11.6,2.2);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.6,2.2)-- (11.584597952190476,2.9736025163350672);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.584597952190476,2.9736025163350672)-- (7.,3.);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.6,1.6)-- (11.6,0.8);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.6,0.8)-- (6.8,0.8);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (6.8,0.8)-- (6.8,1.6);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (6.8,1.6)-- (11.6,1.6);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.6,0.2)-- (11.6,-0.6);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (11.6,-0.6)-- (6.6,-0.6);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (6.6,-0.6)-- (6.6,0.2);
\draw [color=zzttqq,line width=3pt] (6.6,0.2)-- (11.6,0.2);
\draw(9.566051220738322,4.243465214617333) node[anchor=north west] {hi};
\draw (-0.003126415538731179,0.18471185186201763) node[anchor=north west] {test};
\draw (9.343856693580186,2.8658591462368794) node[anchor=north west] {test};
\draw (9.180914040330887,1.354936361561543) node[anchor=north west] {test};
\draw (8.766150922969032,-0.12636048615937515) node[anchor=north west] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can format your code by clicking on`{}`...

Comment: The image that you have shown is a  Word's SmartArt. You could use to draw your picture using the `smartdiagram` package for TikZ .

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. This isn't a tree, doesn't use arrows and has nothing to do with creating bookmarks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that the question is how to draw this more efficiently, or better. The picture is really just two triangles with some text scattered over the top. In order to make this easier to customise, I have defined coordinates `(A)`, `(B)` and `(C)` for vertices of the triangle, starting from the top and reading clockwise, and then drawn everything relative to these coordinates.

The text in the boxes on the triangles appears as a comma separated list inside the `\foreach` loop. Here is the output:

[image]

...and here is the code:

```
  \documentclass[10pt]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \definecolor{leftcolour}{HTML}{21bdbe}
  \definecolor{rightcolour}{HTML}{19bfe0}

  \begin{document}

      \begin{tikzpicture}[
          nodetext/.style={draw=leftcolour, very thick, rectangle, anchor=south west,
                           fill=white,minimum height=2em},
          lefttriangle/.style={draw=leftcolour,fill=leftcolour},
          righttriangle/.style={draw=rightcolour,fill=rightcolour!50}
        ]
        \coordinate (A) at (0,8.5); % top          - formerly (8,5.8);
        \coordinate (B) at (6,0);   % bottom right - formerly(11.6, -1.2);
        \coordinate (C) at (-6,0);  % bottom left  - (3.6,-1.2);
        \draw[lefttriangle]  (A) -- ($ (C)!0.5!(B) $) --(C) -- cycle;
        \draw[righttriangle] (A) -- ($ (C)!0.5!(B) $) --(B) -- cycle;
        \foreach \word [count=\c, evaluate=c as \y using \c/5,]
           in {Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Test 4} {
              \node[nodetext, minimum width=\c*26mm] at ($ (A)!\y!(C)+(-0.3,-0.42) $){\word};
        }
     \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

The following two fudge factors might need to be fine-tuned:

- the text boxes have an offset of `(-0.3,-0.42)`, since the square root of 2 times 0.3 is about to 0.42
- the minimum width of text box number `\c` is set to `\c*26mm`

Finally, the number of text boxes can be changed by replacing `\c/5` in the line

```
\foreach \word [count=\c, evaluate=c as \y using \c/5,]
```

to `\c/6` etc. Of course, do to this properly you probably need to adjust the coordinates `(A)`, `(B)` and `(C)`. Of course, in principle, this could be automated too.

**EDIT**

Here is sgmoye's centering improvement from the comments. I have changed the width "offset" of the node to `\c*25mm`:

[image]

and the modified MWE:

```
  \documentclass[10pt]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \definecolor{leftcolour}{HTML}{21bdbe}
  \definecolor{rightcolour}{HTML}{19bfe0}

  \begin{document}

      \begin{tikzpicture}[
          nodetext/.style={draw=leftcolour, very thick, rectangle, anchor=south,
                           fill=white,minimum height=2em},
          lefttriangle/.style={draw=leftcolour,fill=leftcolour},
          righttriangle/.style={draw=rightcolour,fill=rightcolour!50}
        ]
        \coordinate (A) at (0,8.5); % top          - formerly (8,5.8);
        \coordinate (B) at (6,0);   % bottom right - formerly(11.6, -1.2);
        \coordinate (C) at (-6,0);  % bottom left  - (3.6,-1.2);
        \draw[lefttriangle]  (A) -- ($ (C)!0.5!(B) $) --(C) -- cycle;
        \draw[righttriangle] (A) -- ($ (C)!0.5!(B) $) --(B) -- cycle;
        \foreach \word [count=\c] in {Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Test 4} {
              \node[nodetext, minimum width=\c*25mm] at (0, 8.5-1.85*\c){\word};
        }
     \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: If you change `anchor=south west` to `anchor=south`, then you can use `\node[nodetext, minimum width=\c*26mm] at (0, 8.5-1.85*\c){\word};`. That ensures that the text boxes are centered, and simplifies the code. The `1.85` is a finagle which could be automated if there were a lot of these graphics to be created.

Comment: @sgmoye Thanks. The centering is very nice. I'll add it as an edit to show explicitly what your improvement does.